# Are there any Postbuses left in the UK?

Tags: uk, buses, mail

For a number of years, Royal Mail operated Postbus services, in rural areas of the UK. These delivered the mail, as well as carrying passengers. In many places were the only sort of public transport, even if they weren't very fast.

But it seems a lot of postbus services have been cancelled in recent years. Are there any left, that you can still travel on? Where do they go?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did some research. There's plenty of travel websites mentioning postbuses as a useful form of transport, in various parts of the UK - are they all out of date or incorrect? Maybe the Royal Mail is the best source, but their website claims there's 'numerous' routes, and they are 'nationwide'.

Comment: @pnuts I don't understand this logic on a Q&A site. The whole point of this site is to ask and answer questions. If people found their answer through research then there's no point to this website existing!

Comment: @lightswitchr The asker could have got their answer faster just by Googling. It would have taken less of their time, and less of our time. Further, the primary sources are less likely to go out of date than this page, so this page is likely to cause confusion in the future, rather than help people.

Answer (score 16):

The only one I can find that still exists is [Route 134](http://www.royalmail.com/you-home/your-community/postbus/routefinder?routeid=3153), which runs Tongue-Talmine-Tongue-Lairg in Highland, Scotland. All other routes seem to have discontinued.

Comment: @pnuts it seems the Royal Mail *are* lying, or at least their site's copy is very much out of date.  If you go to find a route, you can choose any of six regions to get a list of all the postbus routes in that region.  For all the regions except *Highland,* the result is *Sorry, no results were found for your search.*  For Highland, there is one result, which is, you guessed it, Tongue-Talmine-Tongue-Lairg.

Comment: "Please note: our Western Isle routes will be ending on 31 March 2016." - might have changed there

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen But, still, the page pnuts links claims "daily services nationwide". Western Isles plus Highlands isn't close to all of Scotland, let alone "nationwide".

Comment: If that's the only remaining route, I'm surprised it hasn't had more media coverage. Could be the last chance to travel on a postbus, before this part of rural heritage is gone.

Answer (score -1):

There don't appear to be any Postbus routes left in Great Britain

Comment: Interesting, the search still finds the route mentioned in the other answer but clicking on the search result leads to an error page.